# Casting IEnumerable<dynamic> with custom class

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable, dapper

I've been using dapper lately and wanted to make a dynamic method that would make it easier to select things out with sql.
This is my code:

Class:

```
public class Method
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> QueryAll(string table)
    { 
        dynamic dyn = table;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbCon"].ToString());
        using (con)
        {
            string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", table);
            IEnumerable<dynamic> ie = con.Query<dynamic>(sql, null);
            return ie;
        }

    }
}
```

Calling function here:

```
IEnumerable<posts> = Method.QueryAll("posts");
```

It gives me an error `that I cannot convert IEnumerable dynamic to IEnumerable Models.Posts`.

How can I cast it to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically you could just use the `IEnumerable.Cast`-method to cast every instance returned from the method to the actual instance.

```
IEnumerable<posts> = Method.QueryAll("posts").Cast<posts>();
```

However if you allready *know* the the actual type why not use it in the query allready? `dynamic` should be handled with care and only if your really have to, which I doubt is the case here. You could for example add the actual type as type-parameter to the method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> QueryAll<T>(string table)
{ 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbCon"].ToString());
    using (con)
    {
        string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", table);
        IEnumerable<T> ie = con.Query<T>(sql, null);
        return ie;
    }
}
```

Now you can call it as follows:

```
var result = Method.QueryAll<posts>("posts");
```

As an aside `Method` is a really bad class-name, as `posts` also. You should give your class names that describe what they serve for and what they are doing. Moreover there are naming-conventions suggesting to use `PascalCase`-names for class making your class `Posts`. At last when you have an enumeration of `posts`, I suppose the class itself represents one single post, not many, so you actual want a class named `Post` which you can store into an `IEnumerable<Post>`.

Comment: Thank you for brief answer. Your solution brighten me up, I haven't thought about using IEnumerable T. About the class names, it was only for  this example case but yeah, I could try a little harder with name choices.

Comment: I my case the return type of the class is really unknown. What is the solution in this case ?